# I have all access to everything enabled for authenticated users by ID, but row level security is not working (Supabase)

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

I am trying to get row level security on my supabase project so that only authenticated users with the right auth.uid() can access only their own projects. I am able to enter projects into the database with the correct information, however, it is not letting me read the files. I am attaching an example of the configurations that I have for the current RLS, the current projects layout, and the code that fetches the projects. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

[image]

fetchingcode:

```
export async function getProjects() {
 let { data: projects, error } = await supabase
   .from("projects")
   .select("*")
   .order("created_at", { ascending: true });
 if (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
 console.log(projects);
 return projects;
}
```

Comment: Where are you writing this `getProjects()` function in your application? If it's being executed on the backend, you need to use auth helpers. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs

Comment: @dshukertjr it is on the backend

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you need to use the auth helpers that I linked in the previous comment in order to fetch data from Supabase as an authenticated user.